# How to make query into arrays?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using this code to gather information from database

```
$webdata = "SELECT * FROM `settings`";
 if (!$web_data = $db_connect->query($webdata)) {
     die('Oops, something went wrong during loading data! Error x010');
 }
```

but now I would liek to display it like arrays so taht I can just simply use this code:

```
<?php echo $web_data['web_name']; ?
```

to display the information

Comment: What is `$web_data`? Post the `var_dump($web_data);`.

Comment: I was using this to display data
`<?php while($webdata = $web_data->fetch_assoc()) {  echo $webdata['web_description'];  }?>`

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this `mysqli`, you need to *fetch* the results into an array.

You can do so with [mysqli's fetch_assoc():](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
$webdata = "SELECT * FROM `settings`";
if (!$web_data = $db_connect->query($webdata)) {
     die('Oops, something went wrong during loading data! Error x010');
}

while ($row = $web_data->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['web_name'];
}
```

Comment: the thing is that I'm already using that what I call "loop", I would make the function teh way so that I can sue just `<?php echo $web_data['web_name']; ?>`

Comment: The above will work. If you have additional code, update your question.

Comment: Wait, this is not what I want: here is more precise example I've done now:  `function webdata($data)
 {
  $data = array();
  $func_num_args = func_num_args();
  $func_get_args = func_get_args();
  
  global $db_connect;
  if ($func_num_args > 1) {
  unset($func_get_args[0]);
  
 $web_data = "SELECT * FROM settings";
 $webdata = $db_connect->query($webdata);
  while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) { return ($data); }
 }
 }`


`<?php echo webdata("web_name"); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Echo will just send **Array** text in response.
To send an array use **print_r** function.